# jGrowl how to close notifcation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jgrowl

In my jgrowl message, your asked to answer either Yes or No, both runs a ajax call, and on success i wish to close the notification, how can i do that, is there a line to close, because right now they all are on timers(life), so they close themselves if i dont make them "sticked"

Comment: It's pretty late, but depending of the nature of the ajax call you are making, if you had any way to relate the caller context to the response handler, it wouldn't be that hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the nature of the ajax call you are making, if you had any way to relate the caller context to the response handler, it wouldn't be that hard to do.

Indeed if you do not have an identifier you could 'create it' (i.e. as a GUID) and use it within the callback function.

i.e. using jQuery AJAX

```
var myId=this.id;
$.ajax{
(...),
success:function(){
 alert(myId);//still visible from within this place
},
(...)
}
```

If you add this identifier to the jGrowl panel (hidden perhaps), that should be enought to do the trick.

Now, I added in a fiddle the modified code of something I've used in the past, just in case it get's erased, I'll leave it here too. This is the fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/MCNUw/12/

html

```
<html>
<body>
    Open
    <div class="classOpen" source="d1">
        div1
    </div>
    <div class="classOpen" source="d2">
        div2
    </div>
    &nbsp;<br>
    Close
    <div class="classClose" source="d1">
        div1
    </div>
    <div class="classClose" source="d2">
        div2
    </div>

</body>
```

css

```
.classOpen{color:green;}
.classClose{color:red;}
```

js

```
var jGrowlConstraints=
{
    jGrowlNotifSelector:'.jGrowl-notification',
    jGrowlCloseThickSelector:'.jGrowl-close'
}

$(".classOpen").click(
    function(){
        var $domElement=$(this);
        $.jGrowl("<span source='"+$domElement.attr("source")+"'/>"+$domElement.html()
                 ,{ sticky: true });        
    }
);

$(".classClose").click(
    function(){
        var $domElement=$(this);
        $(jGrowlConstraints.jGrowlNotifSelector)
        .has("[source="+$domElement.attr("source")+"]")
        .find(jGrowlConstraints.jGrowlCloseThickSelector)
        .click();
    }
);
```

wish I would have seen your question earlier to help you then